# Eclipse: Can't copy input.txt file into src?

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to copy a text file (input.txt) into my src folder.  Unfortunately, I get:

"A resource already exists on disk '/Users/me/Desktop/Programming/HandHistoryConverter/src/input.txt"

However, input.txt doesn't appear in my src folder in the folder menu on the left in Eclipse.

Any idea how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the folder on disk? If it's not in eclipse it could still be in the actual folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking it away from your folder and adding it to your src folder (in eclipse) by dragging it in. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the `File` menu you can find `Refresh`. Using `Refresh` will solve it.

(Or, just restart your Eclipse for the last resort...)

Comment: I managed to *seemingly* get input.txt into my src folder but when I try to move it into my default package, Eclipse says "file of that name already exists"...

Comment: There might be `input.txt` in your default package, too.